# How do I use the interface for this number reverse program, instead of using the program entry itself? (JAVA)

Tags: java

I need to know how to add the input as the number to be reversed. This questions answer should help anyone who has the need to make an input go into a program and come out modified.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberReverse {

public int reverseNumber(int number){

    System.out.print("Enter a number: "); <------ input

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String input = keyboard.nextLine();

    int reverse = 0;
    while(number !=0){
        reverse = (reverse*10)+(number%10);
        number = number/10;
    }
    return reverse;
    }
    public static void main(String a[]){
        NumberReverse nr = new NumberReverse();
        System.out.println("Result: " +nr.reverseNumber(Where I want the input to go / or you can put a number here inside of the program, instead of using the interface.));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think best way to handle input in the main method and then trigger to reverseNumber with input value;

```
public class NumberReverse {

 public int reverseNumber(int number){


int reverse = 0;
while(number !=0){
    reverse = (reverse*10)+(number%10);
    number = number/10;
}
return reverse;
}
public static void main(String a[]){
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");   
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        try {
            NumberReverse nr = new NumberReverse();
            System.out.println("Result: " +nr.reverseNumber(Integer.valueOf(input)));

        } catch (NumberFormatException nme) {
             System.err.println("You entered not numeric value...!");
        }


  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the number as the argument of the main:

```
public static void main(String a[]) {
    NumberReverse nr = new NumberReverse();
    System.out.println("Result: "+ nr.reverseNumber(Integer.parseInt(a[0])));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want interface, then remove Scanner statements and pass number as argument like below

```
    public int reverseNumber(int number){

       int reverse = 0;
        while(number !=0){
           reverse = (reverse*10)+(number%10);
           number = number/10;
        }
      return reverse;
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){
        reverseNumber nr = new reverseNumber();
        System.out.println("Result: " +nr.reverseNumber(52));  //pass the number you wish to reverse
    }
```